# vuejs3 : can't import axios globally

Tags: javascript, axios, vuejs3

I can import and use axios in a component:

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default function usePostLogin() {
 const login = async (url , data , callback) => {
    axios.post(url, data)
// etc
```

I want to import axios globally.

In main.js :

```
import axios from 'axios'

const app = createApp(App)
app.component('FontAwesome', FontAwesomeIcon)
app.use(createPinia()).use(router).use(axios)
app.mount('#app')
```

But then I get an error :  `error  'axios' is not defined  no-undef`

Answer (score 1):

You can not add axios with `use` in Vue3, in main.js add it to the global property:

```
app.config.globalProperties.axios = axios
```

and in component use it like:

```
this.axios
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask: where is this documented?

Comment: @thiebo hey mate, you can look at Vue3 documentations: https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties